# Entity List Contains Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a EF model where two entities have M-to-M relationship like:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.InverseProperty("Received")]
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Message> ReceivedMessages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<User> Received { get; set; }
    public Message()
    {
        this.Received = new System.Collections.Generic.List<User>();
    }
}
```

At some time I have IDs of 2 users and want to check if there are messages related to only these 2:

```
B.Models.User U1 = db.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == ID1);
B.Models.User U2 = db.Users.Single(u => u.UserId == ID2);
B.Models.Message header = db.Messages.Single(m => m.Received.Count() == 2 && m.Received.Contains(U1) && m.Received.Contains(U2));
```

However I get an error that only primitive values can be used in this context. I don't have an entity that contains UserId and MessageId so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could find any Messages with exactly 2 Users containing Users with both ID1 and ID2:

```
db.Messages.Where(msg => msg.Received.Count() == 2 && msg.Received.Any(user => user.UserId == ID1) && msg.Received.Any(user => user.UserId == ID2));
```

If you use the `Single` method as in your question it would throw an exception if it found more than one Message which matched that criteria.  `Where` will return a IEnumerable which you can cast to a list or use in a foreach.

The reason why `Contains` did not work in your example is because Contains is a method of the ICollection interface and is not supported by Linq-to-Entities.  The `Any` method is functionally similar though it is better to check for the equality of the IDs than it is the equality of the reference.